# php framework for querying data from remote db

Tags: php, database, yii

I am building an web application for monitoring data in our database which is on a remote db .

it involves generating complex queries based on user selection .

which php framework is best suited for this type of application ?

Comment: Which ones have you looked into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for my experience, for working with databases I prefer no framework at all, just pure SQL. Especially if you need to build flexible queries, the added value of the framework will be hugely shaded off by added bullshit of it... Not everyone will agree I now, the portability etc. etc., but if you need flexibility and not need so much database portability then just go without framework.

Comment: Thanks guys . what folder structure do i use then ? I just want it to be easy to add new data or query and have separation of layers and have all queries in one place instead of in the page .

Comment: @Rakesh, you can use the MVC (model view controller) pattern - be sure to study this first. Almost every modern web framework is built using this design pattern. Regarding folders, its up to you, you can get inspired by existing projects.. (e.g. Joomla).

Answer (score 0):

It depends,

**if you want to learn new, use new framework.**

**If you have a short deadline, use a framework you know better.**

Answer (score 0):

Frameworks typically are not that good for complex queries since they most often have their own ORM - or at least implement an existing ORM framework. When constructing complex queries in such frameworks the end result is poor performance due to the nature of practically all ORMs. If you are generally writing a reporting application then I would recommend at least NOT using any ORM for this and crafting the queries yourself. In that regard, then, you are free to choose any framework that makes it easy to construct a site and simple write your own queries to power the data behind the pages.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any framework for executing queries. Instead you need query optimisation for better performance..

However, if you are interested in `MVC Framework` that deals with `ORM`, then there are few well known `MVC frameworks` that you may consider. Some of them are:

- [Zend](http://www.zend.com/en/)
- [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/)
- [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/)